# How do I make my table view's cell selection based on a stepper value, not the physical selection of the cell in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How do I make my table view's cell selection based on a stepper value, not the physical selection of the cell in swift 3?

I want to transfer data to another view controller from a table view. I have this transfer occurring based on a segue right now. Currently my code takes the selected cell's information and passes it into the next view controller's label as it is supposed to through the function tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath). I now want the identification of what is to be sent to be based on the value that is read in the label connected to the stepper in the cell, not the physical selection of the cell. In other words how do I equate the selection of the cell to having a value greater than 0 inside the label inside the cell.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you are wanting to control the data passed, based on the value of your stepper, no matter which tableViewCell is selected?

If so inside of your segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifer == "(your segue ID)") {
        let vc = segue.destination
        vc.dataSource = tableViewDataSource[stepperValue]
    }
}
```

or:

```
let vc = yourDestinationViewController
vc.dataSource = tableViewDataSource[stepperValue]
self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

keep in mind this is pseudocode because I don't know what kind of objects you are using but I hope this helps to point you in the right direction.  If you are grabbing the stepper value as a string, you will need to cast it to a Int.

Comment: What are you saying the stepperValue is? Is that the name of the label that the stepper is connected to or is it something else. Please explain.

Comment: That is up to you really, you can pull that value from your label, or from the stepper.  I personally would pull it from the stepper itself, going straight to the source of the value, instead of "beating around the bush" :)

Comment: How do you call the value from the stepper then? When I use your "stepperValue" the error of use of unresolved identifier comes up. Do I have to declare this as something? If I do, where should I do this? Where I declare the stepper or in the segue function or somewhere else? Please help

Comment: So I tried to make the "stepperValue" a variable and define it as the sender.value. A new error popped up and says that the 'UIViewController' has no member 'dataSource'. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: dataSource in this pseudocode would be the Dictionary or Array that you are using to populate your tableView.  So just use whatever variable you are using to create your tableViewCell's view inside `func dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier: String, 
                     for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`